# how listView item add content in editText box?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

How to add listView item content in editText box when user touch on liistView item

[image]

Comment: You should add your code to your question, so you get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to take EditText object

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Now you need to set onItemClickListener on listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        et.setText(item);             
    }
});
```

I am  assuming your are using normal adapter with string as an item as you haven't shown any specific customadapter code.

Comment: it will display the `id` instead of `content` right ?

Answer (score 0):

To make the list clickable, apply `OnItemClickListener`

In order to get the content, you need to define the position of the object, then use setText, and get the content based on the position.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

            Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults) o;
            String content = fullObject.getContent();
                Content.setText(content); // set content to your Content editText 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:
    Initalize the textView**

```
EditText etSetText ;
etSetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EDITTEXTID);
```

**Step 2:**
    **Handle OnClickListner of ListView
    Get Clicked Item
    Set Text to the Initialized TextView**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            String selectedText = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            etSetText.setText(selectedText)
        }
 });
```